# Connecting any two(multiple) forms based on the event triggered

Tags: c++, events, qt4, qt-creator

I have a mainwindow with pushbutton1 and a subwindow with pushbutton2.When I click the pushbutton1 on my mainwindow I should show my subwindow while hiding the mainwindow.Similarly when I click the pushbutton2 on subwindow,I should close the subwindow and come back to my mainwindow.

Also how can I get some event from another program or file and connect it here?
Am using QtCreator2.0 with ubuntu 10.10.AnY help or advice are greatly accepted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For communication beetwen qt classes in one process you can use [signals and slots](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/signalsandslots.html).

For interprocess communication you can use [DBus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus).
Look at [Qt docs on DBus](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/intro-to-dbus.html).

ps. Do you really need two window? and not QStackedWidget?

Comment: Thank You for the response.I had done with signals and slots.Yes I need to have multiple screen for a out-going call and based on the events I need to connect between the screens.So far I had done this using a creator and making a second screen visible by using the following code: static *Form = new form(this)             Form->Activate();   Form->show();     Form->raise();         Here,I don't want to repeat these lines of code in every form to show the other.So please help me with a better solution.